# How to generate and add privacy policy on Google Play?

Tags: google-play, privacy, geolocation

I have to create and add a privacy policy to my Android app. My app accesses background geolocation data, so whatever policy I add has to include info about how location data is used. Two questions:

1. Is there a standard approach to creating a privacy policy? For example, is there a template that people usually use, that I would be able to add an extra geolocation clause to?
2. Where in the Google Play console do you add the privacy policy? I went to `Store Presence -> Main Store Listing` and didn't see any place to add a privacy policy.

Comment: There are some online tools for generating a privacy policy e.g., https://trickuweb.com/free-privacy-policy-generator/
Just paste the generated privacy policy on your website and provide a link on Google Play Store

Comment: Found https://github.com/nisrulz/app-privacy-policy-generator which is using https://www.privacypolicytemplate.net

Answer (score 60):

1. As far as I know, there is no specific standard for the privacy policy. You can have a look at the policies of other reputed apps to get an idea on how to write it. There is no hard and fast rule of the writing style either (remember, this is neither legislature nor a court of law). I think the policy should be written in simple and clear English that everybody can understand. Many of the free privacy policy generators use legal wording, which I want to avoid unless absolutely necessary. It is good to mention the following clearly in the privacy policy:

   - The data your app stores, and which of these is "personally identifiable information".
   - The data your app transmits to your servers.
   - How the above data is used.
   - Whether it is possible to request deletion of this data.
   - The permissions that your app use, especially if you use any sensitive permissions like `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.
   - Why the app requires those permissions.
   - How you want to be contacted in case someone wishes to ask for clarification/deletion of data/report security vulnerability.
2. In the Play Console, first click on the app. There is a left pane with many options like Dashboard, Inbox, Releases, etc. Scroll down on that pane to the bottom, and there you will find "App content". Click on that, and you will find a place to add a link to your privacy policy.

Note that the privacy policy has to be uploaded somewhere else, and you can only put the link to it in Google Play. My apps, for example, are all open-source, so I have uploaded the privacy policy to GitHub and linked to it. Another good option, if your app is closed-source, and you don't have a website, is to create a single GitHub repo for all the privacy policies of your apps, and then individually link those files in Google Play and in the app.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a link to your GitHub privacy policy?

Comment: @David Sure, here it is: https://github.com/WrichikBasu/ShakeAlarmClock/blob/master/PRIVACY_POLICY.md

Comment: Thanks! You added some things I had not considered that I'm sure to use myself.

Comment: In "App content", you might need to go to the "Treated" tab to find a place to add a link to your privacy policy.

Answer (score 45):

i use the following website for my apps privacy policies
https://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/
very simple you don't need to write the entire thing you just fill in some questions and they offer to host the policy on their site and provide you with a url to set in your store listing

Comment: Not totally free.  Certain options cost money. I decided to select all the options... The maximum you'll pay is "Price for this premium Privacy Policy: 264 USD (tax excl.) One-time payment. No recurring fees."  And then decided, NOPE!  On top of that.. they want to send you this in a email.

Comment: you don't need to select all options for play store basic privacy policy , this is not for all privacy policies it only fits  the question asked

Comment: Okay, let me clear this up. Options cost $10+ dollars each, Do you use tracking, send emails? Users pay for stuff? have marketing & advertising purposes? use Invisible reCAPTCHA? need CCPA wording, GDPR wording, CalOPPA wording? collect from kids? <<-- Those are the options that cost $$$.  Also they need your email address: Your e-mail address to receive the Privacy Policy.  Why?  Because they can sell your email address to also make money!  Clearly a business website.  If it was "free" there would be no need for an email address.

Comment: This is not a true free website. They just want your email address. I do not trust this at all.

Comment: It's also just a skin of: https://www.privacypolicies.com

Answer (score 32):

## **Update after the announcement of Launching of Data safety in Play Console**

[Link to October 2021's announcement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/10/launching-data-safety-in-play-console.html)

The [Google Play's support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469?hl=en) now mentions that:

> All developers that have an app published on Google Play must complete
> the Data safety form, including apps on internal, closed, open, or
> production testing tracks.
>
> Even developers with apps that do not
> collect any user data are required to complete this form and provide a
> link to their privacy policy. In this case, the completed form and
> privacy policy can indicate that no user data is collected or shared.

I did not find any official Google standard/template for the privacy policy either.

Even if my application was not collecting/sharing any information, I decided to follow the steps below in order not to be penalized at a later stage.

#### To write my application's Privacy Notice

- I reviewed some policies of reputed applications (as suggested by
  [Wrichik Basu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66343513/4862968));
- I used and customized the [template provided by docracy](https://www.docracy.com/6016/mobile-privacy-policy) for Mobile Privacy Policy (free, no registration needed). The website mentioned by [Bilal Rammal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66349855/4862968) is interesting if your app requests specific permissions (which was not my case).
- I consulted the [GDPR-compliant privacy notice](https://gdpr.eu/privacy-notice/?cn-reloaded=1).

#### To host my application's Privacy Notice

I uploaded this privacy policy on my [personnal website](https://timetocount.antoineauger.fr/privacy.html) and I checked that it was publicly accessible.

You may want to double check the file permissions and `.htaccess` rules if you self-host/manage your website.

#### To update my app information in the Google Play Console

- I opened Play Console and went to the [App content](https://play.google.com/console/app/app-content/summary) page (`Policy` > `App content`).
- Under "Privacy Policy," I selected **Start**.
- I entered the URL hosting the privacy policy online.
- I saved my changes.

*Note: If you’ve previously added a privacy policy and want to make changes, you’ll see and select **Manage** instead of start.*

#### In my application

- I reviewed the permissions that I was requesting;
- I included a link (in the "Settings" section) to my Privacy Policy so that users of my application can easily review it.

Comment: From the posted link "The Docracy product is no longer available to use."

Comment: @Mick Thanks for letting me know. If you have any free alternative feel free to post it as a comment and I'll edit my original post. I found [Termly] (https://app.termly.io/builder/websites/0882ebd6-560f-46b2-aa33-4092addb7fe8/documents/3160074/Privacy%20Policy%20Uses/Privacy%20Policy%20Uses) but unfortunately you need to sign up in order to download the privacy notice generated.

Comment: I ended up doing something informal, following a couple of the other posts I read on this forum. I won't know if it is good enough until I finally upload to play store in perhaps a month or so.